# Getting rows with duplicate column values

Tags: sql

I tried this with solutions avaialble online, but none worked for me.

```
Table :
Id rank 
1  100
1  100
2  75
2  45
3  50
3 50
```

I want Ids 1 and 3 returned, beacuse they have duplicates.

I tried something like

```
 select * from A where rank in ( 
 select rank from A group by rank having count(rank) > 1
```

This also returned ids without any duplicates. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010311/how-to-check-if-all-fields-are-unique-in-oracle

Comment: Duplicate question, the irony! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053569/is-it-possible-for-sql-to-find-records-with-duplicates

Comment: @JCooper: Sorry. I looked up online before posting. Tried couple. But didnt know I need to group by both id and rank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id from table
group by id, rank
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: This gives me Id with more than one value. I am trying to get the ones with duplicates. Thanks

Comment: Yeap sorry, correected it. I missed the rank

Comment: Thank you. :) I dont know what I would do without these forums and you guys. Learning each time..:)

Comment: Welcome ^.^ Anyway, this is not a forum -- The main difference is that all the interaction here is asking a question, answering the question, voting it and accepting answers. Nothing else :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, rank
from
(
    select id, rank, count(*) cnt
    from rank_tab
    group by id, rank
    having count(*) > 1
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

This general idea should work:

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT rank) = 1
```

In plain English: get every `id` that exists in multiple rows, but all these rows have the same value in `rank`.

---

If you want `id`s that have *some* duplicated `rank`s (but not necessarily all), something like this should work:

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > COUNT(DISTINCT rank)
```